# Override function without if statement

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Three models have `ImageField` which refers to one function, with `if`. Is there any suggestions how to perform this function without if?

```py
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    _, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

    if isinstance(instance, (Story,)):
        return f'stories/{instance.id}/cover{extension}'
    elif isinstance(instance, (Episode,)):
        return f'stories/{instance.story.id}/{instance.index}/cover{extension}'
    elif isinstance(instance, (EpisodeSlide,)):
        return f'stories/{instance.episode.story.id}/{instance.episode.index}/{instance.id}{extension}
```

Comment: Use dictionary mapping your locations?

Comment: I think your original code is fine; the logic is clear. You needed a function whose behavior depends on the type, so you made a function whose behavior depends on the type. You could split into three unrelated functions, but if you want to be able to call this the same way on all three types, what you have is the way to go. If you had many more such repeated if-statements, consider a dict from types to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Dennis: if statements make the code very readable. Following is 
my attempt at a solution without using `if`. Perhaps there are better ways, for example using `format` statement instead of "f-strings" and, as @Dennis suggests, perhaps using type as the key.

```py
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    lookup = dict([
        (Story.__name__, lambda instance: f'stories/{instance.id}/cover{extension}'),
        (Episode.__name__, lambda instance: f'stories/{instance.story.id}/{instance.index}/cover{extension}'),
        (EpisodeSlide.__name__, lambda instance: f'stories/{instance.episode.story.id}/{instance.episode.index}/{instance.id}{extension}')
    ])

    _, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    loc = lookup[instance.__class__.__name__](instance)
    return loc
```

```
print(upload_location(e, "hello.txt"))
print(upload_location(es, "hello.txt"))
print(upload_location(s, "hello.txt"))

stories/1/10/cover.txt
stories/1/10/100.txt
stories/1/cover.txt
```

To repeat, if-statements are much better than the above function!!

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Prasanth